# Busqueda en lista de archivos

Tags: python

deseo hallar el registro(linea) que coincida con un parámetro de búsqueda en un listado de archivos(txt) para lo cual tengo el siguiente código:

```
import csv
def encontrar_ruc(file, ruc):
    with open(file) as csvfile:
        reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile, delimiter='\t')
        for row in reader:
            if row["NUMERO_RUC"] == ruc:
                yield row

fileList = ['PICHINCHA.txt','TUNGURAHUA.txt']
for f in fileList:
  registros = list(encontrar_ruc(f, "1804464194001"))
print registros[0]['RAZON_SOCIAL']
```

el error que genera:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 13, in <module>
    registros = list(encontrar_ruc(f, "1804464194001"))
  File "test.py", line 7, in encontrar_ruc
    for row in reader:
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/csv.py", line 104, in next
    row = self.reader.next()
_csv.Error: new-line character seen in unquoted field - do you need to open the file in universal-newline mode?
```

agradezco cualquier sugerencia..!!

Comment: Prueba con `with open(file, 'rU') as csvfile:` ¿El csv se generó en un sistema Windows (con Excel quizás)?

Comment: saludos, desconosco dado que lo descargo de un servicio gubernamental "http://www.sri.gob.ec/DocumentosAlfrescoPortlet/descargar/3a946aa3-1da1-4add-85eb-03a40dfa20ae/TUNGURAHUA.zip"

Comment: acabo de correr tu código y me funciona bien. Al final muestra el nombre "LOACHAMIN AVILA DIEGO ALBERTO". Quizas sea ignorancia mía pero por que importas csv si tu archivo de ejemplo es un texto plano con extension .txt?. Supongo que usas  python 2.7 en mi caso uso la version 3.6.